# Aligning two numbers, one on top of the other

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm looking to do something like this, but I'm not sure how.[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \textunderscore & \textunderscore \\
  \textunderscore & 1 & \textunderscore & 1 & 1 & 0 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit of an overkill, but the input syntax is somewhat easier, since spaces delimit the numbers. This uses macros designed for lining up word for word glosses in linguistics. The braces around the `\tu` are required, however. If the numbers have more than one digit, they will align to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cgloss4e} % part of gb4e package but you don't need it all
\newcommand*{\tu}{\textunderscore}
\begin{document}
\gll 0 1 0 1 {\tu} {\tu}\\
    {\tu} 1 {\tu} 1 0 0 \\

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: for some reason, the underscores are too wide; for alignment where only digits are involved, the underscore should be the same width as one digit, and perhaps it should also sit on the baseline, not under it.

Answer (score 2):

With `verbatim`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
  0 1 0 1 _ _ 
  _ 1 _ 1 1 0
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```